# Connect to a network via the command line

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, remote-desktop, script

I want to be able to connect to a network via command line in Windows.  My goal is to script out remoting into my work computer.  I hate having to always manually connect to the VPN connection and then rdping into my work machine.  I want to just have a script which will do both of it for me.  I know how to rdp via command line, I just need to know how to connect to my VPN via command line.

Comment: What VPN software are you using? There may be different ways to control the VPN connection from the command line based on the software (Cisco, OpenVPN, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the `netsh` command which can be used to control the network in many ways?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a microsoft VPN, the built-in command you are looking for is "rasdial". As far as I can tell, netsh won't help.

After you've set up your VPN connection, use

```
rasdial <VPNName> <username> *
```

to request a password and initiate the connection. Unfortunately, I don't know a way to use the password saved via the GUI. Then use

```
rasdial <VPNName> /DISCONNECT
```

to end the connection. For other options, of course use rasdial /?

If you aren't using the built-in Microsoft VPN drivers, then you will need to use a command line utility specific to your VPN vendor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect a wireless network before you have connected, and network profile is saved, you can run:

```
netsh wlan connect ssid="WIFI_SSID" name="PROFILE_NAME" interface="NETWORK INTERFACE"
```